# не стартуют контейнеры с mongoDB и mariaDB в docker-compose

Tags: база-данных, docker, mongodb, docker-compose, mariadb

использую docker-compose для старта контейнеров:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mariaDB:
    image: mariadb:10.7
    restart: always
    container_name: maria_db
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    depends_on:
      - mariaDB
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:8080

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo_db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example


  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    container_name: mongoDB_express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

контейнеры находятся постоянно в restarting:

```
root@debian:/home/user/test# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
5e2e128fd721        adminer             "entrypoint.sh docke…"   24 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds                   0.0.0.0:7777->8080/tcp   adminer
8dfb5a7c0254        mongo-express       "tini -- /docker-ent…"   24 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds                    0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   mongoDB_express
509375e2cef3        mariadb:10.7        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago      Restarting (1) 6 seconds ago                             maria_db
8a5bcc64b9f3        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago      Restarting (100) 1 second ago                            mongo_db
```

docker logs maria_db:

```
2022-08-04 19:27:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.4+maria~focal started.
2022-08-04 19:27:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-04 19:27:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.4+maria~focal started.
2022-08-04 19:27:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-08-04 19:27:17 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Error writing file './ddl_recovery.log' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device")
2022-08-04 19:27:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-08-04 19:27:17 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Error on close of '(null)' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql/ for more information.

The problem could be conflicting information in an external
my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:

    shell> /usr/bin/mariadb-install-db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf

You can also try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mariadbd --skip-grant-tables --general-log &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mariadb
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql/ that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at https://mariadb.org/jira
```

docker logs mongo:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.747+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.748+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.752+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.752+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.753+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.755+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.755+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.756+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.756+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.757+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":28,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"8a5bcc64b9f3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.757+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.757+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.757+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/1/fd/1"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.758+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.759+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22312,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error creating journal directory","attr":{"directory":"/data/db/journal","error":"boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: \"/data/db/journal\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.759+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20558,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"std::exception in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: \"/data/db/journal\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.759+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.760+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.762+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.762+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.762+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.762+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:01.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28

{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.620+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.621+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.622+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.626+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.626+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.629+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.629+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.629+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.629+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.630+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":28,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"8a5bcc64b9f3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.630+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.630+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.630+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/1/fd/1"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.632+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.632+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22312,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error creating journal directory","attr":{"directory":"/data/db/journal","error":"boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: \"/data/db/journal\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20558,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"std::exception in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device: \"/data/db/journal\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.635+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T19:28:53.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

В MariaDB загружен дамп рабочей и исправной базы данных, которая стартовала спокойно 5 часов назад.
В MongoDB не загружено ничего, полностью пустой образ, даже так он отказывается запускаться

С базами данных и СУБД я до этого не работа и не могу сам найти решение проблемы